# Telling pushpins apart in Bing Maps

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, pushpin

If I smack up a series of pushpins (some from an array of data and some added by the user with a click), I'd like some magic to occur when the rat hovers over them.

So I've added an event on *mouseover* which gets me an alert. The problem is that I'd like to vary what's in the alert. How can I set an ID, name or such on each of the pushpins?

I'm going to use that to unfold a *DIV* later on, because, as far I could see, there's no functionality in the AJAX component itself that opens a frame when clicking or hovering over a pushpin.

## Edit

For now, I'm creating a pushpin and appending an own field to it like so.

```
var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(latitude, longitude);
pushpin.info = { ... };
pushpins.push(pushpin);
```

Will I be sorry for this hack and, if so, in what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added custom fields to pushpins to track my own objects and it works fine. I wouldn't call it a hack, you're just extending the pushpin object.